# Change menu option width with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have got a menu on my homepage and on hover I would like them to enlarge. This is exactly what I have achieved, except there is one flaw:

When I move off before the animation ends, the option stops the animation and subtracts 30 from the width that left off from the previous animation. So it always intersects with the other animation and causes false results.

### Example:

> I move quickly to menu option 1, it only expands little - let's say by 10px - while I am on it, and as I move off the width decreases by 30px, which is more than the previously moved 10px, which results in a smaller button overall.

I would like to somehow capture how much it has moved during the mouseover animation and only decrease the width in the leaving function by that amount. Or, of course some other easy solution, if there is one...

Here's the code:

```
    $('.menu_option').hover(

        function() {

            var w = $(this).width()+30+"";
            $(this).stop().animate({ width:w}, 150, 'easeOutQuad');

        }, function() {

                var w = $(this).width()-30+"";
                $(this).stop().animate({ width:w}, 150, 'easeOutQuad');

        });
```

Comment: try `stop(true, true)` instead of `.stop()` so that the queued animation will get completed

Comment: @ArunPJohny Nope, unfortunately does not work...

Comment: can you share the markup and css, possible a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: if you see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qBLPa/3/ has the problem

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yes that is exactly the problem. If you hover over them too quickly, their width goes to zero...

Comment: see my answer below, it looks like a problem with the order of execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is make another variable which is the origin width then when you put it back go back to the origin:

js:

```
var o = $('.menu_option').width();
$('.menu_option').hover(function () {

    var w = $(this).width() + 30 + "";
    $(this).stop().animate({
        width: w
    }, 150, 'easeOutQuad');
}, function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        width: o
    }, 150, 'easeOutQuad');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/qBLPa/6/

Comment: That's indeed the better solution... Thanks very much!

Comment: Thats ok happy to help

Answer (score 1):

You need to complete the previous animation before the width is calculated

```
$('.menu_option').hover(function () {
    var $this = $(this).stop(true, true);
    var w = $this.width() + 30;

    $this.animate({
        width: w
    }, 150, 'easeOutQuad');
}, function () {
    var $this = $(this).stop(true, true);
    var w = $this.width() - 30 + "";

    $this.animate({
        width: w
    }, 150, 'easeOutQuad');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qBLPa/)

Comment: @MartinE. missed the problem with the order at first

Comment: @MartinE. just saying this stuters